Checking for an option in a multi-select dropdown
I'm working in Google Sheets to attempt to count which cells from a given column contain a specific option included in a multi-select dropdown menu, whether or not other options are selected.
ie: Cards can be Artifacts, Creatures, or Artifact Creatures, and I want to include the row in the calculation if it is an Artifact, or an Artifact Creature, but not if it's just a Creature.



Type
Qty
Reprint?




Artifact
4



Creature
2



Artifact Creature
4



Artifact
4
True



This link
I've attempted a fair few variations on a theme of =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,false,$D$2:$D,QUERY($D$2:$D,"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'Artifact'") with attempts to split it with and without tocol, and with and without commas to deliminate
There should be 13 results, as there are 13 non-reprint cards in this set that are artifacts, but I can only ever get 11 (which excludes the two artifact creatures) or 0.

Can you manually add and showcase your ideal expected output somewhere in the test sheet alongside with some explanation points on why it is supposed to be that way and all...

@rockinfreakshow This isn't really a test sheet, it's being constructed but it's otherwise what I'm going to be working from. The fields in Column H are values that that section is filtering for to help track Set Completion statistics in Magic the Gathering: Arena, to help players (mainly me) remember during quick drafts and similar events which cards are still missing from their collection. For each card that matches the condition, column I is "I have at least one", column J is "I have playsets of 4 cards", and column K is "I need this many more cards to complete the playsets."

How about using this formula?
=Countifs($A$2:$A,false,$D$2:$D,"*"&H18&"*",$F$2:$F,">0")
